# Correct way to use tf.optimizer.Adam to minimize loss with respect to a Variable in Tensorflow Core 2 alpha

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working on implementing a simple Neural Style Transfer in Tensorflow 2. I have already seen this official [Tensorflow tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/generative/style_transfer.ipynb).

I followed the directions in the tutorial to write a training loop:

```
img = tf.Variable(content_img)
for t in range(max_iter):
   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
       tape.watch(img)
       loss = getStyleTransferLoss(img, cnn)
   # Compute gradient
   grad = tape.gradient(loss, img)
   optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad, img)])
```

However, I end up with following error:

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'

I also tried other variants, like getting rid of the GradientTape and directly using optimizer to minimize loss on the img.

```
optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list = [img_var])
```

In both the cases, I end up with the same error.
If I remove optimizer, the loop runs without any error. Even the stacktrace shows that the issue is with optimizer.

The complete stack trace of the error can be found in this [paste link](https://pastebin.com/4mB7FggF).

Comment: Found the error ! Image Variable was getting reinitialized as a Tensor when we clip large and small values after updating the image.

There was another line after `optimizer.minimize(loss, img)` for clipping values.

`tf.clip_by_value(img, -1.5, 1.5)`. This step was reinitializing image Variable as a Tensor. Sorry for asking this question here !

Answer (score 0):

OP reports the solution:

> Image Variable was getting reinitialized as a Tensor when we clip large and small values after updating the image. There was another line after `optimizer.minimize(loss, img)` for clipping values. `tf.clip_by_value(img, -1.5, 1.5)`. This step was reinitializing image Variable as a Tensor.

I will delete this once the OP has followed these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer